# How to continue playing music while mobile phone times out or goes to lockscreen?

Tags: unity, mobile

Is there a way to keep my app/game running in background even when my screen times out and goes to the lock screen on mobile (specifically Android)?

For my purposes, I prefer if it goes to the lock screen / time out screen - I don't want screen on the whole time, but I do want my app/game awake however.

Comment: What does your app need to do while the screen is off? Depending on the specific behaviours, there may be a variety of ways to allow them to keep up with real time, or catch up just in time when the screen turns back on.

Comment: play music/sound tracks while screen is off, playing Audio clips with Audio Sources

Comment: Ah, that might be easier. Want to edit your question to ask "How to continue playing music while mobile phone goes to lock screen?" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play audio in Unity when a mobile game runs in the background or the screen is locked?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197908/how-to-play-audio-in-unity-when-a-mobile-game-runs-in-the-background-or-the-scre)