# Is there a simple way to check for available space on an iOS device within a Unity app?

Tags: unity, operating-system

I was trying to use `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()[0]` to retrieve available disk space but that only works on a computer. I was wondering if there was any simple way to output this information within a Unity app when running on an iOS device.

Comment: Last I heard, no. But that was a few years ago. My point is: if you hunt and cannot find such it thing, it truly may not exist. :)

Answer (score 2):

If the "simple way" you are referring to is a built-in Unity function, **no**, there isn't.

Unity provides an abstraction layer that lets you program once for many platforms. Every core library function has a platform-specific version for each supported platform.

On the other hand, some features may have limited or no support. Features not intended for game development or which developers would rarely use are usually neglected by design.

Most times, if you need such functionalities, you're likely to know what you're doing and have a good programming experience. Hence, you can implement such functionalities yourself.

#### Project setup

To begin with, create a dummy function that returns mock values for the current available space, e.g.:

```
public static float getAvailableSpace() {
    return 0.6f;
}
```

This way, you can keep developing your project and test various scenarios for different amounts of free space. Change the function arguments according to your needs.

You are going to change the actual implementation another time, but you need to export your project first.

#### Project export

Platform-specific functionalities can be added to a Unity game by exporting the project and extending it in an external editor, such as Android Studio or XCode.

I address this process and provide a brief overview of Android's and iOS's app architecture in [this previous Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/197956/60302) here on GameDev.SE.

#### Feature implementation

Once you open the project in XCode, you can browse the class of interest to find the dummy function you previously implemented, and extend its functionalities to query the available space on the device. [This previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26198164/4499313) from StackOverflow addresses querying available space for iOS in Swift.